# Kinesis Firehose to put data into multiple Redshift tables

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have records with multiple nested JSON (UDTs) and based on those I have have multiple tables in Redshift: 1 for main json and others for nested json.

Now these input records need to be saved from `Kinesis Firehose` to `Redshift`. While configuring Redshift as destination there is an option to provide only one table through AWS console.

Is there any way of configuring more than one Redshift table as a destination for Kinesis Firehose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems only one Redshift table can be configured as the Firehose destination.

> A single delivery stream can only deliver data to one Amazon Redshift cluster and one table currently. If you want to have data delivered to multiple Redshift clusters or tables, you can create multiple delivery streams.

Reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/faqs/